# Jquery Ajax how to do polling on Clientside

Tags: jquery, ajax, websocket, polling, long-polling

I am familiar with using Jquery Ajax for to make webservice calls. I am trying find some simple code examples that will poll based on some condition. (ie, request data for webpage or download a file and check every few seconds and process the results or wait until  process is complete).

Is there any step by step Examples ? How does it handle, if takes 30 sec to 10 mins or longer? How is the polling handled for long periods? and show it on the dashboard/user on how far is lefts before completion.

I'm familiar with how to use AJAX in jQuery, I just can't seem to find the "proper" way of getting  about to execute using a timer and exit outwhen the process is done or there is failure.

Comment: longpolling is mostly handled by the server-side. on the client it's nothing more than an ajax request with a longish timeout that repeats when complete.

Comment: What server side technology are you using?

Comment: @ErikPhilips - Server side is Java. I am more interested in the client side how to handle the polling/wait time using Jquery/AJAX until the process is complete